# Change mouse cursor color when left button is held down - Windows

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am trying to change cursor color when the mouse left button is in the 'hold down state'. This is supposed to work in Windows 10, so something at the OS level, not in any specific program. I would like to do this to know when "ClickLock" is enabled.
Is there anyway to achieve this?

I have tried with Autohotkey but nothing happens

```
; Cursor types
IDC_APPSTARTING :=  32650

~LButton::
while GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
     {
        ; this is the code to the Dll call, but I am not sure how to integrate it
         hCursor:=DllCall("LoadCursor", "UInt", NULL,"Int", IDC_APPSTARTING, "UInt")
         DllCall("SetCursor","UInt",hCursor)
     }
return
```

Answer (score 1):

For more info, please refer to: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32608-changing-the-system-cursor/

```
IDC_APPSTARTING :=  32650

~LButton::
    changeCursor(IDC_APPSTARTING)
Return

~LButton Up::
    changeCursor()
Return

changeCursor(cursor := 0) {
    if (cursor) {
        CursorHandle := DllCall("LoadCursor", Uint, 0, Int, cursor)
        Cursors = 32512,32513,32514,32515,32516,32640,32641,32642,32643,32644,32645,32646,32648,32649,32650,32651
        Loop, Parse, Cursors, `,
            DllCall("SetSystemCursor", Uint, CursorHandle, Int, A_Loopfield )

    } else {
        DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt, 0x57, UInt, 0, UInt, 0, UInt, 0 )
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that helps! Is the loop really needed? I actually seeing some of the cursors being changed when I click.

Comment: It is working as intended, unfortunately I think the ClickLock function doesn't trigger the LButton so AHK doesn't detect it. I mean the cursor changes when ClickLock is active but doesn't change to the cursor I have slected, strange.

Comment: It's working as intended on my end. I'll need more details.
The loop is needed. Follow the link I posted for more information on why.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Let me give you more details. For example if I use the 
~LButton::
    changeCursor(IDC_HELP)
Return
When I am on Firefox and I click on links the cursor icon changes to the red circle with diagonal bar, when I click else the icon turns into the IDC_HELP icon. When I am in Firefox for example and I want to select text, the cursor turns into "I", while ClickLock is active the cursor turns into the normal cursor, instead of the IDC_HELP, but when i am between lines of text it switches back to the IDC_HELP until I reach the next line of text.

Comment: So here's the other strange part, when I click again, which disables ClickLock releasing the mouse button, if the cursor was the normal cursor, then the cursor turns back into the "I", otherwise if the cursor was IDC_HELP, it turns into the normal cursor. Sorry this is probably easier to show than explain. It's inconsistent anyway. You can easily replicate by trying to select text.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried anything yet? I would say probably start googling. I came across a few different resources on the first try that pointed me in the direction of the registry keys, and even a nifty powershell script to set them on demand. Do a little research, bro. Happy coding.

Comment: I definitely did search but maybe I am using the wrong keywords, I only found results that are software specific, will try again...